# syntax error near unexpected token `fi' (run Script)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a problem to run my script in Ubuntu Server.
I want to execute this command:

```
sudo ./grantperm.sh
```

But I get this error:

```
“Creating“chmod“chown“chmod/chown./grantperm.sh: line 29: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./grantperm.sh: line 29: `fi'
```

The code is written this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
ocpath='/var/www/nextcloud'
htuser='www-data'
htgroup='www-data'
rootuser='root'

printf “Creating possible missing Directories\n”
mkdir -p $ocpath/data
mkdir -p $ocpath/updater

printf “chmod Files and Directories\n”
find ${ocpath}/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0640
find ${ocpath}/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0750

printf “chown Directories\n”
chown -R ${rootuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/
chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/apps/
chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/config/
chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/data/
chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/themes/
chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/updater/

chmod +x ${ocpath}/occ

printf “chmod/chown .htaccess\n”
if [ -f ${ocpath}/.htaccess ] then
chmod 0644 ${ocpath}/.htaccess
chown ${rootuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/.htaccess
fi
if [ -f ${ocpath}/data/.htaccess ] then
chmod 0644 ${ocpath}/data/.htaccess
chown ${rootuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/data/.htaccess
fi
```

Could you helpme to fix the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You have "smart" quotes (`“...”`) in your script - change them to normal "straight" ASCII quotes (`"..."`).

Comment: The first problem fixed but y give new error: ./grantperm.sh: line 29: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./grantperm.sh: line 29: `fi'

Comment: Well, you also don't have any `then` keyword (try adding `;` or newline before your existing non-keyword `then` tokens).  But you really should have reduced this to a [mcve] first - and you'd have likely found the error on your own if you had!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash `if` statements require `;` before `then` if written on a single line.

Or you could write

```
if [ -f ${ocpath}/.htaccess ] then
```

on two lines:

```
if [ -f ${ocpath}/.htaccess ]
then
```